# to extract lines appearing inbetween { } in text file through batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can we extract lines appearing between { } in text file through batch file.

### Text file would be in format:

```
Name : ABC
Place : xyz
Data :dd/mm/yyyy

{"return":"good","message":"ABC is present in xyz place","SSN":"-----------------345679HISKWBXMVTXVEULWXVC\nVBXSWGVXBWSDCXLWUDV"}
```

I tried using the below code snippet, However it lists all the contents of text file . How can we extract the contents within {}

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (filename) do set extract=!extract!%%x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims={}" %%a in ("Whateverfile.txt") do set "data=%%a"
echo %data%
```

type for/? in cmd for more info or [For-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)